# Is there is any possible way to edit subscription interval of Authorize.Net after payments start?

Tags: authorize.net, recurring-billing, authorize.net-arb

How to edit subscription interval after subscription starts? As I enter subscription interval as 12 of every month instead of every month in Authorize.Net.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the interval after a subscription starts. If you want to change the interval you will need to cancel the current subscription and create a new one with the new interval period.